# codeigniter : how print response of page into log_message?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in CodeIgNiter. I want to print the response of server into log_message. In simple when one page called by other that time what response sent by server to calling page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply try something like this

Controller.php

```
  function some_function(){
      ....
      $response = some code ...
      log_message('level', $response);
  }
```

Comment: Finally i got answer through my friend.

log_message("debug","response from page..........".$_SERVER["REDIRECT_STATUS"]); 

$_SERVER["REDIRECT_STATUS"] will give responce code of the page. 


Thanks to everyone for valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In application/config/config.php

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 2;

and 

log_message('debug/error', 'your message');
```

Try this:

```
class MY_Output extends CI_Output {

    protected $_enable_log_output = TRUE;


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent:: __construct();

        log_message('debug', 'MY_Output Class Initialized');
    }


    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Display Output
     *
     * Processes sends the sends finalized output data to the browser along
     * with any server headers and profile data. It also stops benchmark
     * timers so the page rendering speed and memory usage can be shown.
     *
     * Note: All "view" data is automatically put into $this->final_output
     *   by controller class.
     *
     * @uses    CI_Output::$final_output
     * @param   string  $output Output data override
     * @return  void
     */
    public function _display($output = '')
    {
        // Note:  We use globals because we can't use $CI =& get_instance()
        // since this function is sometimes called by the caching mechanism,
        // which happens before the CI super object is available.
        global $BM, $CFG;

        // Grab the super object if we can.
        if (class_exists('CI_Controller', FALSE))
        {
            $CI =& get_instance();
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        // Set the output data
        if ($output === '')
        {
            $output =& $this->final_output;
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        // Is minify requested?
        if ($CFG->item('minify_output') === TRUE)
        {
            $output = $this->minify($output, $this->mime_type);
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        // Do we need to write a cache file? Only if the controller does not have its
        // own _output() method and we are not dealing with a cache file, which we
        // can determine by the existence of the $CI object above
        if ($this->cache_expiration > 0 && isset($CI) && ! method_exists($CI, '_output'))
        {
            $this->_write_cache($output);
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        // Parse out the elapsed time and memory usage,
        // then swap the pseudo-variables with the data

        $elapsed = $BM->elapsed_time('total_execution_time_start', 'total_execution_time_end');

        if ($this->parse_exec_vars === TRUE)
        {
            $memory = round(memory_get_usage() / 1024 / 1024, 2).'MB';

            $output = str_replace(array('{elapsed_time}', '{memory_usage}'), array($elapsed, $memory), $output);
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        // Is compression requested?
        if ($CFG->item('compress_output') === TRUE && $this->_zlib_oc === FALSE
            && extension_loaded('zlib')
            && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING']) && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip') !== FALSE)
        {
            ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        // Are there any server headers to send?
        if (count($this->headers) > 0)
        {
            foreach ($this->headers as $header)
            {
                @header($header[0], $header[1]);
            }
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        // Print output in log
        if($this->_enable_log_output)
        {
            log_message('debug', $output);
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        // Does the $CI object exist?
        // If not we know we are dealing with a cache file so we'll
        // simply echo out the data and exit.
        if ( ! isset($CI))
        {
            echo $output;
            log_message('debug', 'Final output sent to browser');
            log_message('debug', 'Total execution time: '.$elapsed);
            return;
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        // Do we need to generate profile data?
        // If so, load the Profile class and run it.
        if ($this->enable_profiler === TRUE)
        {
            $CI->load->library('profiler');
            if ( ! empty($this->_profiler_sections))
            {
                $CI->profiler->set_sections($this->_profiler_sections);
            }

            // If the output data contains closing </body> and </html> tags
            // we will remove them and add them back after we insert the profile data
            $output = preg_replace('|</body>.*?</html>|is', '', $output, -1, $count).$CI->profiler->run();
            if ($count > 0)
            {
                $output .= '</body></html>';
            }
        }

        // Does the controller contain a function named _output()?
        // If so send the output there.  Otherwise, echo it.
        if (method_exists($CI, '_output'))
        {
            $CI->_output($output);
        }
        else
        {
            echo $output; // Send it to the browser!
        }

        log_message('debug', 'Final output sent to browser');
        log_message('debug', 'Total execution time: '.$elapsed);
    }
}

/* End of file MY_Output.php */
/* Location: ./application/core/MY_Output.php */
```

Comment: Thanks guys for your response but i want to know how i can print server response like(200, 505, 404). 

like server ip address log_message("debug","server ip address is ....... ".$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']);

so for server responce what i will write instead of $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'].